# ffmpeg - How to pass http headers?

Tags: http, video, command-line, ffmpeg, http-headers

I need to pass http headers (user agent and ip) to an ffmpeg command.

I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg  -y -timeout 5000000 -map 0:0 -an -sn -f md5 - -headers "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36" -headers "X-Forwarded-For: 13.14.15.66"  -i "http://127.0.0.1"
```

And I run a local node.js server to see the headers I get:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');

var server = express();

server.all('/*', function(req, res) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));
  res.sendFile('SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4', {root: '.'});

});


server.listen(80);
```

I keep getting an error saying "No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header." and the request is stuck.

If I drop the headers - everything works normally.

I also tried putting both headers in one string, but any line breaking character I used (\r\n, \r\n, etc.) didn't work.

Can someone help me figure out how to write this command correctly with the headers included?

Comment: Just curious: did you also try using two separate `-headers "<foo>\r\n"` options, each with their own `\r\n` at the end of the option argument strings?

Comment: Yes. It didn't work.
I think I tried the full matrix of duplicating slashes, joining headers, etc.

Comment: What specifically is the issue you are seeing with sending them? What does the receiver get?

Comment: Actually I just set up a small local server to test - and it seems I am never able to send any headers what so ever (even if it is just one header)

Comment: My goal is just to calculate the md5 of a video file, so this is pretty much what I need from this command.
I ran trace like you did, but I don't see my headers being sent on the request.

Comment: can't you use the `md5` program? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - my code obviously does more than just an md5 calculation. This is just the first command in the flow.

Comment: you wrote "My goal is just to calculate the md5 of a video file". Good luck.

Comment: Just one more question... Is there any way to remove some of the defaults headers? For example, by default, it adds a 'Range: bytes=0-' header, but it's generating me a '406 Not acceptable' response.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Short Answer

Make sure you're using the latest `ffmpeg`, and use the `-user-agent` option.

### Longer Answer

For debugging, I setup a [`BaseHTTPSever`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer) running at `127.0.0.1:8080` with `do_GET()` as:

```
def do_GET(self):
   try:
       f = open(curdir + sep + self.path, 'rb')
       self.send_response(200)
       self.end_headers()
       print("GET: "+ str(self.headers))
       self.wfile.write(f.read())
       f.close()
       return

   except IOError:
       self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)
```

With that running, this enabled me to run your command like:

```
ffmpeg  \
    -y \
    -timeout 5000000 \
    -map 0:0 \
    -an \
    -sn \
    -f md5 - \
    -headers "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36" \
    -headers "X-Forwarded-For: 13.14.15.66" \
    -i "http://127.0.0.1:8080/some_video_file.mp4" \
    -v trace
```

When I do this, I see the following relevant output from `ffmpeg`:

```
Reading option '-headers' ... matched as AVOption 'headers' with argument 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36'.
Reading option '-headers' ... matched as AVOption 'headers' with argument 'X-Forwarded-For: 13.14.15.66'.
```

On the server, I saw:

```
User-Agent: Lavf/56.40.101
X-Forwarded-For: 13.14.15.66
```

So it looks like `ffmpeg` is setting it's own. But there is an option `-user-agent` to `ffmpeg`, and when I replaced `-headers "User-Agent: <foo>"` with `-user-agent "<foo>"`, I then did see it too on the server, alongside the `X-Forwarded-For` header:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
```

Last note. There are lots of discussions around headers bugs in trac for `ffmpeg`. What I have observed above (that essentially it *is* working, perhaps with a small command change) was with a fairly recent version:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
configuration: --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --cc='gcc -fPIC'
libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

So, your next move might be make sure you have the latest version of `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @shellter awesome glad it helps!

Comment: @Jameson, the user agent worked for me, but when i'm trying to set up the ip - I'm still getting the "No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header." error

Comment: Upgrading the ffmpeg version solved the second issue. I'm accepting the answer.

Comment: @Lizozom awesome, glad we got it!

Comment: Here is example commands for any HTTP header.  http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/passing-http-headers-to-ffmpeg/

Comment: In a new version ffmpeg says that user-agent ist deprecated and user_agent should be used instead.

Comment: for user agent u need to use -user_agent options to make it work precisely

Answer (score 18):

Well, ffmpeg manual says to split multiple http-headers by CRLF. The problem is that you overwrite your first "-header" argument with the second "-header" as there can be only one "-header" argument.

For your example, you need to join `User-Agent` and `X-Forwarded` into one argument by valid CRLF like this:

`-header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"$'\r\n'"X-Forwarded-For: 13.14.15.66"$'\r\n'`

Answer (score 10):

For set `x:1` and `y:2` for header ffmpeg request, use this:

```
ffmpeg -headers $'x:1\r\ny:2\r\n' -i 'http://sample.com' -y 'sample.mp4' -v debug
```

Result:

```
[http @ 0x358be00] Setting default whitelist 'http,https,tls,rtp,tcp,udp,crypto,httpproxy'
[http @ 0x358be00] request: GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/57.76.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
x:1
y:2
```

Comment: It seems the order is also important. If you put -i before -headers they'll be ignored. -headers first works well.